# Running bash script as Cron job with R Markdown

Tags: linux, r, bash, cron

I want to try how to render html from R markdown file but from a bash script running as Cron jobs. I don't know why everything works fine, except running as Cron jobs. What I do:

My script is a demo script from Rstudio

````
---
title: "test"
author: "sms"
date: "24 maja 2015"
output: html_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```
etc.
````

This script works without any problem in Rstudio.

Next I try to run an Rmd script from terminal:

```
Rscript -e "require( 'rmarkdown' ); render('/home/sms/Dokumenty/R/test.Rmd', 'html_document')"
```

There wasn't any problem. It works.

So I create bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Rscript -e "require('rmarkdown'); render('/home/sms/Dokumenty/R/test.Rmd', 'html_document')"

and changed chmod 755 test.sh

Also works like a charme.

But when put in Cron file (admin and user):

```
28 18 * * * sh /home/sms/Dokumenty/R/test.sh
```

It doesn't works

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
 The issue is because I was running the Rscript as root, but Rscript should be run as souza, current user.
 To fix that, I edited the crontab for user souza "sudo crontab -u souza -e" and the Rscript is run as souza and not as root.
 Now it is working

Answer (score 1):

Simplify, simplify, simplify.

First, I'd make it an Rscript, maybe called `renderTest.R`

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(rmarkdown)
setwd("/home/sms/Dokuments/R")
render("test.Rmd")   # I usually use default arguments
```

Second, make the script executable (`chmod 0755 renderTest.R`).

Third, test the script.  If you can run it as you, a cron job running as you should too.

Fourth, add the cronjob running as *you* to have the same rights.

*Edit* I just fixed a typo I copied from you: `Documents/` not `Documenty/`.

Comment: Dirk, thank you,

There's still problem when I run your script
test.sh: 3: test.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: If it helps, please consider "accepting" (click on tick-mark) and/or "upvoting" (click on upward-triangle) both of which are common at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did not write a script `test.sh`. You did. I suggested _an Rscript file_ named `renderTest.R`.

Comment: it works in terminal, but when I write whole path to script, even when I'm in correct directory
/home/sms/Dokumenty/R/test.sh

Oh, Ok. I see. Your script is an R script.

Comment: Simplify, simplify, simplify.  Find which commands work, and which don't. Comment things out til they work, then add. _Debug_.

Comment: I do everything and: Rscript /home/sms/Dokumenty/R/renderTest.R and it works but only in terminal.
But the same command doesn't works as a cronjob

Comment: Test a simpler `cronjob` first.  Recall that it is five entries for "when", one for "who" and one for "what" in `/etc/crontab`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problems.

But it would work if you try to use knitr::knit2html instead of rmarkdown::render

on idea why